# Python avoid nesting when checking multiple conditions

Tags: python, conditional-statements

I have this python conditions

```
a=a_foo()
if a==True:
  b=b_foo():
    if b==True:
      c=c_foo()
      if c==True:
         d=d_foo()
      else:
        print('c error')
    else:
      print('b error')
  else:
    print('a error')
```

The code is working, but if i use this conditions for a-z, the code seems bad.

What a better solution ?

EDIT :

Thanks for comment, i will use `if a` instead of `if a == True`

also `a_foo, b_foo, c_foo` functions is only example, can be `function1,func2,funcother,etc`

and last, the function also have parameter, example `a_foo(p1, p2)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to list the functions that you want to call. However, you will need some way of identifying which function failed:

```py
funcs = [a_foo,b_foo,c_foo,d_foo]   # add more functions as required

for f in funcs:
   if not f():
        print(f.__name__, "error")
        break
```

If you want to have different sets of parameters with each function:

```py
funcs = [(a_foo,),(b_foo,b),(c_foo,c,d),(d_foo,d,e,f)]   # add more functions as required

for f,*args in funcs:
   if not f(*args):
        print(f.__name__, "error")
        break
```

Comment: how if each function have different parameter

Comment: this is what i looking for, thanks for answer

Answer (score 2):

You can simply put functions and messages into a list of tuples:

```
# each element is a tuple with a function to execute and error message when result is False
functions_with_messages = [(a_foo, 'a error'), (b_foo, 'b error'), (c_foo, 'c error')]

for function, error_message in functions_with_messages:
    function_result = function()
    if not function_result:
        print(error_message)
        break  # optional if you want to stop execution of next functions
```

It would be more idiomatic than the hack-y way of getting function's name with `function.__name__`. It can be also easily translated into other programming languages.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in a function and then you can return from it so there's no need to keep nesting.

```
a = a_foo()
if not a:
    print('a error')
    return

b = b_foo()
if not b:
    print('b error')
    return
```

Answer (score -2):

2  line solution here.

```
from string import ascii_lowercase
[print(i) for i in ascii_lowercase if eval(f'{i}_foo()')]
```

Comment: It's a nice one-liner but using `eval` is bad in general, see [Why is using eval a bad practive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice).

Comment: I know but still it's a one-liner.

Comment: It might be a one-liner, but it is not a good solution. Just because you can do a thing, doesn't mean you should do a thing.